# 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'loss'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am doing churn prediction using keras. I have used column transformer from Sklearn. My code is--

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

def keras_classifier_wrapper():
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(9, input_dim=13, activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return clf

clf = KerasClassifier(keras_classifier_wrapper, epochs=20, batch_size=50, verbose=0)
categorical_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
])
numerical_pipe = Pipeline([
   ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'))
])
 
preprocessing = ColumnTransformer(
    [('cat', categorical_pipe, cat_var1),
     ('num', numerical_pipe, num_var1)])
 
model3 = Pipeline([
    ('preprocess', preprocessing),
    ('keras_clf', clf)
])

model3.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But it showing an error-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-162-1f0472b386ae> in <module>()
----> 1 model3.fit(X_train, y_train)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py in fit(self, x, y, **kwargs)
    157       self.model = self.build_fn(**self.filter_sk_params(self.build_fn))
    158 
--> 159     if (losses.is_categorical_crossentropy(self.model.loss) and
    160         len(y.shape) != 2):
    161       y = to_categorical(y)

AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'loss'
```

Can you plz tell me why this error is showing and how to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is in your keras_classifier_wrapper function

```
def keras_classifier_wrapper():
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(9, input_dim=13, activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return clf # should be return classifier
```

you are trying to return clf but there is no clf it is defined afterwards. try to return classifier then it will work

Comment: showing another error  ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_5 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 13 but received input with shape [None, 119]

Comment: your input dimensions are not the same (probably because one hot encoder) try to change the input_dim to 119, should work this way

Comment: my X_train is -(460798, 13) and y_train is =460798 which is binary classification only Treue & False

Comment: I have 13 features that's  why I gave input_dim =13

Comment: i understand but you are not feeding the network with that 13 features, you used one hot encoder so its not 13 anymore. try to use one hot encoder outside the pipeline and check how many features you have, it should be 119.